# ANTLR4 Best practice on token ambiguities: Lexer predicate, or Parser tree walker

Tags: antlr, antlr4, ambiguity

I have a question about a certain ambiguity I am encountering in a grammar I am currently working on. Here is the problem, in brief. Consider these two inputs:

```
1010
0101
```

In isolation, in my grammar the first input is interpreted as a decimal number, the second as an octal due to the leading zero.

However, if the preceding character to each of these sequences is a `%` then both would be interpreted as a binary number. This wouldn't be a problem if we stopped there.

Now, let's say before the `%` we encountered a `5`, what would happen? Does my grammar consider each of these as valid input:

```
5%1010
5%0101
```

The answer is "Yes!" The rightmost sequences of `1`s and `0`s simply revert back to decimal and octal, respectively, and the `%` is a modulo operator.

This wouldn't be a problem if expressions in my grammar only consisted of digits, but that unfortunately is not the case, as any number of non-digit tokens could substitute for the `5` in the example above, like variables, braces, and even other math operators like parentheses and minus signs.

The solution I have come to in ANTLR is simply to have an expression rule where one of the alternatives concatenates an expression and a binary number, so you have:

```
expr
    :    expr Binary 
    |    expr '%' expr
    |    Integer
    |    Octal
    |    Binary
    ;    
 
Integer
    :    '0'
    |    [1-9] [0-9]*
    ;
    
Octal
    :    '0' [0-7]+
    ;

Binary
    :    '%' [01]+
    ;
```

I then leave it up to my visitor to actually "pull apart" the right hand side of the expression type above (the `expr Binary` one), and properly calculate the modulo, which means I have to "re-tokenize" essentially the `%` and following digits.

I guess my question is: Is this the best solution given my case? I fully accept it if so, but I am curious if others have had to resort to things like these.

I cooked up a lexer predicate to do some crazy lookaheads (and lookbehinds) in the input, but my instinct was this felt wrong, as I was essentially hand-parsing, rather than leveraging the tool itself to give me enough what I needed to work with.

Comment: The subtleties of using left-look context free grammars for parsing/lexing programming-like languages are notoriously hard to grok. I'll be really impressed if someone offers a studied piece of advice here. I've debugged problems with grammars like this and at the end I didn't feel like I really learned anything, just struggled through it until it worked. Good luck!

Comment: I suggest to require spaces around mathematical operators (including the %), which would solve your problems without any additional work. A `%` followed directly by digits is a `Binary`, period. Regardless of the context it was found in. If a user wants a modulo operation instead, (s)he has to add a space after `%`. It's better style anyway.

Comment: Thanks @MikeLischke for the feedback. That is indeed a solution I've considered, a reasonable one, too, considering the ambiguity I'm facing. It reminds me a bit of the C++ issue with the >> in template parameters. I'm only hesitant because the spacing requirement isn't one we see typically in languages.

Comment: Yes, that shift operator issue also came to my mind, but also in other languages such restrictions exist. For example in MySQL a built-in function name can be used as table name if directly followed by an opening parenthesis (see the [IGNORE_SPACE sql mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space)).